# Handling lists and one element not list type

Tags: python, list

There are many functions in python that return a list of elements. If there is only one element, they return the element instead of a list containing one element. Therefore, code such as `for element in returnedList` doesn't work for the case when there is only one element.

What's the proper way to handle this situation? I can check if the return value is not a list and then do `returnedList = [returnedList]` but this is messy and there has got to be a way to do it better since so many functions behave like this.

For example with matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = range(0, 10)
y = x
N = 2

f, axis = plt.subplots(N, 1, sharex=True)
for ax in axis:
    ax.plot(x,y)

plt.show()
```

will work for N > 1, will fail for N = 1 since axis is not a list of axis but rather a single axis.

Comment: Can you try doing `plt.subplots(N, 1, sharex=True, squeeze=False)` ? I can't test your code.

Comment: Do you want a generic solution how to nicely make a single element a list if it is not a list already, or a solution for that `matplotlib` function?

Comment: I saw this behavior before in other libraries so I thought I had totally missed a simple way to handle it, perhaps some kind of enumerate that accounts for that and everyone uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't that many functions that behave like that, exactly for the reason you stated. [`plt.subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) tries to provide a convenience for users creating a single subplot, or a row or column of subplots. This behavior can be turned off easily using the `squeeze` parameter, in which case `axis` will become a 2D numpy array.

You can do

```
f, axis = plt.subplots(N, 1, sharex=True, squeeze=False)
for ax in axis.ravel():
    ax.plot(x,y)
```

The call to [`ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ravel.html) ensures that you have a 1D array in all cases.

For a more general solution, you have some options. If the shape of the result depends on the input, you can use an `if` statement:

```
if N == 1: axis = [axis]
```

If the type of return iterable is known up-front, e.g., `np.ndarray`, you could use `isinstance`:

```
if not isinstance(axis, np.ndarray): axis = [axis]
```

And finally, you could use exception handling:

```
try:
    for ax in axis:
        ax.plot(x, y)
except TypeError:
    axis.plot(x, y)
```

This can be rephrased to avoid redundancy:

```
try:
    iter(axis)
except TypeError:
    axis = [axis]
```

All the cases, specific or general, are messy. Having very different types of return values is not a good design for this exact reason. Unfortunately, you have to find some way to compensate if the function doesn't let you turn it off.

Comment: Im marking yours as solution since it's the more complete.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap calls to such functions like this:

```
>>> from typing import Iterable
>>> def ensure_iter(a):
        if isinstance(a, Iterable):
            return a
        else:
            return [a]


>>> ensure_iter([])
[]
>>> ensure_iter('fred')
'fred'
>>> ensure_iter(1)
[1]
```

Comment: I quote OP : `I can check if the return value is not a list and then do returnedList = [returnedList] but this is messy`.

Comment: And I was proposing to tidy the mess away.

Comment: You're just moving it under the carpet to me, but ok :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple method can be to write a function and invoke the function on the returned value. The function can internally convert the result to list if it is not already a list.

A Sample:

```
a = [2,3,4]
b  = 1

def convert(a):
    return a if type(a) == list else [a]

print convert(a)
print convert(b)
```

**Output:**

```
[2, 3, 4]
[1]
```

Comment: I quote OP : `I can check if the return value is not a list and then do returnedList = [returnedList] but this is messy`. Plus, you should check types using `isinstance()` and not `type()`, [here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/what-are-the-differences-between-type-and-isinstance).

Comment: Not to mention that this particular function doesn't return a list as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @MadPhysicist The one liner makes it slightly confusing, but I think it works. See the `else [a]` part. The first value is selected if the condition is right, else...

Comment: I misspoke. Your example works fine. OP's example is dealing with ndarrays

Comment: @IMCoins, Thanks for looking at my answer. I was just proposing one way to make it less messy. :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist, Thanks for looking at my answer and editing it. :)

Comment: I had to edit to remove my downvote. It's very late and I need to get sleep before I do any more stupid stuff.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, We all have been there, Sleep Deprivation. Good Night! :)

Answer (score 0):

Using the parameter squeeze, and modifying your code a little bit.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = range(0, 10)
y = x
N = 1

f, axis = plt.subplots(N, 1, sharex=True, squeeze=False)
for ax in axis:
    ax[0].plot(x,y)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks! That works. But my question is more general, not for that case in particular. I have seen this problem many times before with other functions enough to make me think there is a general way to solve it. It is strange to return an iterable but only the element if there is only one item.

Comment: As you can see from the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) in the **Returns** section, the library explicitly chooses to return such values. There is no "best" way to handle this to me. It is to the discretion of the library owner. Plus, you can see that they offer a way to generalize what you wish to do with the `squeeze` parameter. They explicitly tell you that this parameter smartly transforms the output. And turning it off disables this "intelligence". Well, that's how I read it. :)